# My model has a list of models. How do I load it from the database but limit the number of items in the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails project I have a scenario where a car can have many parking tickets (I am using ActiveRecord). This is how I modelled it

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parkingTickets, :order => "partkingTickets.date DESC"
end

class ParkingTickets < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Car
end
```

And this is how I retrieve data:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:parkingTickets).order('ID, parkingTickets.date desc')
```

This works.
But now I want to get the car only with the tickets from the last 12 months (if the ticket is older, I do not need it).
Is there any way to express this using active record? I would not like to fetch a car and the fetch the parking tickets because this is a list of cars, so I would make many DB calls...

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `where` condition should solve the issue:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:parkingTickets)
           .where('parkingTickets.date >= ?', 12.months.ago)
           .order('ID, parkingTickets.date desc')
```

Comment: wow, 12.months.ago, is that even possible in ruby on rails? this language is amazing!