# Select rows from the last 12 months starting on the last date inserted on the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a system about cars and parking tickets. I had a requirement to implement where I had to get all the tickets from the last 12 months, so I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530925/my-model-has-a-list-of-models-how-do-i-load-it-from-the-database-but-limit-the).

The requirement has changed and now I need to get the tickets from the last 12 months starting on the last ticket's date.

I know how to do that using SQL (postgres), it would be something like this example:

```
select *
from parking_tickets
where car_id = 25
AND
date >  (select date from parking_tickets where car_id = 25 order by date desc limit 1) - INTERVAL '12 months'
order by date desc
```

But I would rather have it in ActiveRecord. Is there any way?

I could insert the subquery itself inside the where clause, but it would not be as nice as I would like to.

Is there a nice way to make this, something like this?

```
@cars = Car.includes(:parkingTickets)
           .where('parkingTickets.date >= ?', MAX(parkingTickets.date) - 12.months)
           .order('ID, parkingTickets.date desc')
```

I would like to have it done in a list of cars, so making the query before and then inserting this value in the query would not be an elegant solution, since I would have an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work:

```
Car.includes(:parking_tickets).where(id: 25, parking_tickets: {date: (ParkingTicket.where(car_id: 25).order(date: :desc).first.date - 12.month)..ParkingTicket.where(car_id: 25).order(date: :desc).first.date}).first.parking_tickets.order(date: :asc).all
```

Comment: I will test at home and get back to you, but I get more amazed by ruby everyday!

Comment: That is working perfectly. One last question: I would like to reference the car_id in the subquery to the actual id coming from the entity car, (I have the car plate as a parameter, not the ID, sorry for the missinformation). How could I reference something like this: car_id: car.id ?
I tried things like this but I couldn't get it working...

Comment: @Oscar: I'm at work right now. I'll show you when I'm at home. Greetings, Arndt

Comment: That would be great! Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: I've done a subquery to get the id form the plate. :)